# Unwanted border in :before/:after pseudo-elements

Tags: css, colors, android-webview, pseudo-element

The code below works fine on desktop browsers. But when applied in an android webview, there seems to be an extra border. Any ideas on how I should deal with this?

```
.container{
          width: 100px;
          height: 50px;
          background-color: #fff;
          color: #000;
          padding: 5px;
          position: relative;
       }
.container:before{
          content: "";
          border-left: 20px solid transparent;
          border-bottom: 50px solid #fff;
          position: absolute;
          left: -20px;
          top: 0;
       }
```

[image: result when rendered in Android webview]

Answer (score 0):

Try with adding `right:100%` instead of `left: -20px` or just give 1 less than actual `left: -19px;`